# ORA-00904 Invalid Identifier: But Column Name is Valid

Tags: sql, oracle

I get the error message

> There is an Error in the SQL Statement, ORA-00904: "70626701":invald
> identifier

when I run the query shown below.

Google search says the problem is an invalid column name, but that column name is used in other places in the query that do not throw an erro.

```
SELECT  
PRODDTA.F4211.SDDOCO AS "Sales Order",
PRODATA.F4211.SDRORN AS "Related PO" ,
PRODATA.F4211.SDVR01 AS "Customer PO",
PRODATA.F4211.SDRKCO AS "Sold To",
PRODATA.F4211.SDRLLN AS "Line Item",
PRODATA.F4211.SDLITM AS "Item Number",
PRODATA.F4211.SDDSC1 AS "Description1",
PRODATA.F4211.SDDSC2 AS "Description2",
PRODATA.F4211.SDDRQJ AS "Req Date Julian",
PRODATA.F4211.SDUOPN AS "Qty",
PRODATA.F4006.OAMLNM AS "Ship To Name",
PRODATA.F4006.OAADD1 AS "Address Line 1",
PRODATA.F4006.OAADD2 AS "Address Line 2",
PRODATA.F4006.OAADD3 AS "Address Line 3",
PRODATA.F4006.OAADD4 AS "Address Line 4",
PRODATA.F4006.OACTY1 AS "City",
PRODATA.F4006.OAADDS AS "State",
PRODATA.F4006.OAADDZ AS "Zip"

FROM 
((PRODDTA.F4211 LEFT JOIN PRODDTA.F4006 ON (PRODDTA.F4211."SDDOCO" = PRODDTA.F4006."OADOCO")))

WHERE
(((PRODDTA.F4211.SDLNTY != "T"))) AND
(((PRODDTA.F4211.SDADDJ IS NOT NULL))) AND
(((PRODDTA.F4211.SDLTTR < "980"))) AND
(((PRODDTA.F4211.SDLITM != "CFO247"))) AND
(((PRODDTA.F4211.SDSHAN != "70789701"))) AND
(((PRODDTA.F4211.SDSHAN != "70789702"))) AND
(((PRODDTA.F4211.SDSHAN != "70626701")))
```

Comment: This is bot true, Oracle doesn't complain about correct SQL text. Check `all_tab_cols`. Also you can easily strip columns from the query unless the error disappear and find the reason by yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in Oracle are to be enclosed into **single** quotes, not double ones.

Therefore, almost the whole `WHERE` clause is wrong, should've been

```
WHERE
(((PRODDTA.F4211.SDLNTY != 'T'))) AND
(((PRODDTA.F4211.SDADDJ IS NOT NULL))) AND
(((PRODDTA.F4211.SDLTTR < '980'))) AND
(((PRODDTA.F4211.SDLITM != 'CFO247'))) AND
(((PRODDTA.F4211.SDSHAN != '70789701'))) AND
(((PRODDTA.F4211.SDSHAN != '70789702'))) AND
(((PRODDTA.F4211.SDSHAN != '70626701')))
```

---

Error you got is kind of misleading; as you enclosed `70626701` into double quotes, Oracle presumed it was a column name, while it was not.